# When using getDerivedStateFromProps, how should you write the constructor?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {}
  }

  getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    return {
      offerX:
        props.canDoX && localStorage.getItem('shouldDoX')
    }
  }
}
```

Or should I define a constructor with `this.state = { offerX: null }` and then let `getDerivedStateFromProps` overwrite it before first render? Is unnecessary logic-wise, but maybe it's helpful for documentation, so a reader knows the format of the state object?

Answer (score 0):

Going according to the readability of the code in the above case then this particular scenario is not specific to using of `getDerivedStateFromProps`, this is applicable to every time when we add a new item to the state which was not defined in the constructor.

About increasing readability of code while defining the state in the constructor; Yes definitely it will be very helpful for the other developer or even for yourself while re-visiting the code that what all states are defining the behaviour and functionality of the component

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reactjs and not react-ts, its always best to specify the initial value of the state objects. It improves the readability of the code but its definitely unnecessary logically if you are using getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state) because it will be returning the objects to state which will be called no matter there is state/props change or not.